# How to get VM which has not Raw physical disk and sort those VM by name provisionedspace?

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I need to get VM List which is to be sort by **provisionedspace** and also those VM should not have **RawPhysical**. I have tried the below code

```
 Get-Datastore -Name "$DSName" |  Get-VMHost | get-vm | Select-Object -Property  Name, Provisionedspacegb | sort -Property Provisionedspacegb | select -First 3 | Select Name
```

The above which is used to get VM list sort by **provisionedspacegb**

```
Get-Datastore -Name "$DSName" | Get-VMHost | Get-VM | Get-HardDisk | Where-Object {$_.DiskType -eq "RawPhysical" } | Select Parent
```

The above which is used to get VM list which does not have **Physical Disk**

I need those two code in a single line powershell code..

Comment: WHY do you need it to be a _single line_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever working with a lot of pipe operators, take a step back and consider divide et impera -approach. That is, break the script in more manageable parts. I don't have VMWare available, but try the following idea:

```
# Get a list of all the VMs
$allVms= Get-Datastore -Name "$DSName" |  Get-VMHost | get-vm

# Array for those we actually want
$rawVms = @()

# Iterate the VM collection. Look for such VMs that have whatever disk config    
foreach($vm in $allVms) {
    # This filtering statement is likely to be incorrect. Tune accordingly
    if($vm | get-harddisk | ? { $_.DiskType -eq "RawPhysical" }).Count -gt 0 {

        # If the VM has raw disk, add it into desired VMs list
        $rawVms += $vm
    }
}

# Do stuff to the filtered collection
$rawVms | Select-Object -Property  Name, Provisionedspacegb | ` # ` = line break for readability
    sort -Property Provisionedspacegb | select -First 3 | Select Name
```

The actual syntax is likely to be a bit different.

Comment: Thank you so much.. You saved my time @vonPryz